# Preventing *.php files from being loaded directly in browser

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I have several form handlers on my website, and I am getting several blank forms submitted to my email daily. I believe it is due to the url of the php file being typed directly into a web browser, as all of the forms use required fields.

After a good bit of searching, I came across a post saying to add a few lines to my .htaccess file. I have done this, but i am still able to type the url of the form handler directly into a browser, and it still sends me an email with the empty form.

this is the code that i added to my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Can anyone provide me with any additional help on how to either get this to work, or another way to stop the form handler from executing and sending me a blank form?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: You need to validate the data coming in. If there is one or more required fields not filled in then you need to send the user back to the input page to complete the data.

Comment: to expand on jeff's comment a very basic option is just  `if(empty($_GET['email'])){exit('missing email')};`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the validity of input on the front end, you can check that the input is set and not empty in the php script, then only send the email if those conditions are met there. It would look something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field_data']) && !empty($_POST['field_data']) && isset($_POST['other_field_data']) && !empty($_POST['other_field_data'])){
    //send mail
}
else{
    die('Error: invalid input');
}
?>
```